# Q_PROPERTY read only instance

Tags: qt, properties

Is there a way to disable write accessors for all properties for a given instance of QObject, effectively turning them into a no-op?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK: No.

The `Q_PROPERTY` macro triggers the `moc` to build the methods at compile time, so there's no way you can change their behaviour at runtime for a particular QObject derived instance.

Comment: Yes, but the properties are dispatched using moc-generated qt_metacall function - I wonder if there is a way to convince moc to generate it under a different name perhaps, and provide my own shim between the two? How configurable is moc anyways?